# Efficient way to manage item positions in grid after rotation/flip in iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, matrix, rotation, grid

I am looking for some guidance on the most efficient way to design a class to manage the position of 3 items in a 6x6 grid.  The items on the grid cannot move/change their position, however, the entire grid can be rotated in 90-degree increments clockwise/counter clockwise and can be flipped horizontally/vertically based on user touch/drag manipulations of the grid in realtime on iOS devices.  As a result of rotating and/or flipping the entire grid, the 3 items in the grid will be in different “absolute” positions based on a non-rotated “position reference” grid.  It is these new item positions I am trying to determine in the most efficient manner after each “transform” of the grid.

To illustrate what I am trying to accomplish, consider the following...
I am numbering the positions in the grid where the upper-left corner is position 0 and numbers increment to the right then down:

Position Reference Grid:

```
-------------------------
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
-------------------------
| 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10| 11|
-------------------------
| 12| 13| 14| 15| 16| 17|
-------------------------
| 18| 19| 20| 21| 22| 23|
-------------------------
| 24| 25| 26| 27| 28| 29|
-------------------------
| 30| 31| 32| 33| 34| 35|
-------------------------
```

I am planning to always refer to an item's position in the grid using this numbering regardless of any rotation/flip transform applied to the grid.  So, for example, if I have items in positions A=7, B=9, C=14

Original:

```
-------------------------
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
-------------------------
| 6 | A | 8 | B | 10| 11|
-------------------------
| 12| 13| C | 15| 16| 17|
-------------------------
| 18| 19| 20| 21| 22| 23|
-------------------------
| 24| 25| 26| 27| 28| 29|
-------------------------
| 30| 31| 32| 33| 34| 35|
-------------------------
```

and rotate the grid 90 degrees clockwise, the new item positions will be A=10, B=22, C=15.

Rotated Clockwise 90 degrees:

```
-------------------------
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
-------------------------
| 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | A | 11|
-------------------------
| 12| 13| 14| C | 16| 17|
-------------------------
| 18| 19| 20| 21| B | 23|
-------------------------
| 24| 25| 26| 27| 28| 29|
-------------------------
| 30| 31| 32| 33| 34| 35|
-------------------------
```

There are just 8 possible orientations of the grid (0, 90, 180, 270 degrees on each side), so each item has exactly 8 known positions based on the orientation of the grid.  As such, I could hard-code 8, 3-item arrays containing the absolute positions of the 3 items for each of the 8 orientations – one array per orientation.  Once I know what orientation the grid is in after some transform, I can simply grab the correct 3-item array of item positions that corresponds to the grid orientation to get the new positions of the 3 items.

Since I need to do this position retrieval for several grids at a time, since the grid transforms are in direct response to touch manipulations on iOS, and since there may be more items in the grids, I am wondering if such hard-coding is the way to go or if there is some more elaborate way to calculate or otherwise dynamically determine the position of the items in the grid once a rotation or flip of the grid has occurred.

Any advice, comments, suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Start by re-numbering grid positions: instead of a straight-through numbering scheme with a cell number, use a two-number scheme, with a `(row, column)` pair. You can easily go back and forth between the two schemes by doing simple math. Make the center of the board be `(0,0)`. Then your points would be located at positions `A=(3,-3)`, `B=(3,1)`, and `C=(1,-1)`.

With this numbering scheme in place, observe that the location of the item can be determined by three things:

- The original `(row, column)` pair
- The rotation (0 - 0°, 1 - 90°, 2 - 180°, 3 - 270°)
- The flip along the horizontal axis (0 - no flip, 1 - flip)

Flipping along the vertical axis is represented by flipping along the horizontal axis followed by a 180° rotation.

Flipping coordinates is easy: change the sign of the `column`, while keeping the row intact. Flipped positions of your points would be `A=(3,3)`, `B=(3,-1)`, and `C=(1,1)`.

A common way of making rotations is by [left-multiplying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) a column-vector of coordinates by a [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix):

[image: Left-multiply:]

Here is a list of matrices to perform rotations by 90°, 180°, and 270°:

[image: Rotate 90°] [image: Rotate 180°] [image: Rotate 270°]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I am familiar with matrix math but was thinking that might be a bit overkill for dealing with a relatively few sets of items and grids.  Nonetheless, I have a few questions about your suggestion as it pertains to my specific data.  See next comment for more...

Comment: You mention setting the center of the board to be (0,0), yet the grid has an even number of rows and columns, so which absolute cell position are you suggesting be used as the center point? Based on your setting `A=(2,-2)` and `(C=1,-1)`, it seems you are suggesting cell 21 from my original post be used as point (0,0).  If so, then `B=(2,0)` not `B=(2,-1)` as you indicate.  Also, after a H flip, the points would be `A=(2,1)`, `B=(2,-1)`, and `C=(1,1)`, so that math doesn't pan out.  It would seem I'd have to mark the true center of the grid (a non-cell) as point (0,0), as if this were a graph.

Comment: @JavaJoe For grids with even number of rows and columns, I suggest using the intersection of lines bordering cells 14, 15, 20, and 21 as the origin. The point `0,0` is not a cell in a grid, it's an intersection of lines. Each cell is two units wide, with points located at odd coordinates, and lines located at even coordinates (I used 2 instead of 3 in my answer - that was incorrect, and it is now fixed). If the grid has odd numbers of rows and columns, I'd move the origin into the central cell, and used one-unit wide cells.